# iOS- UIWebView and downloaded code

Tags: ios, plugins

I know that Apple's terms for apps disallows downloading and executing code, but there seems to be an exception for JavaScript running in a UIWebView:

> 3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework.

Does this mean that I can download and execute interpreted code, as long as it runs in a UIWebView?

I am developing an MMO, for which I would like to allow mods. It would have clients for iOS, Android, browsers, and eventually native desktop clients. I would do it entirely in the browser, but iOS doesn't support WebGL.

Is there a way to do this without violating the license agreement? I would really like to see a full-featured version on iPad, and I would be willing to put these mods in the app store so they can be reviewed, if that's possible.

These mods would be pretty simple, but more complicated than a data file could offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You simply download the Javascript and put it inside script tags using a UIWebView's [`loadHTMLString:baseURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString%3abaseURL%3a) method, and then getting the result of various function calls using [`stringByEvaulatingJavaScriptFromString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) method.  You'd have to define an API where your game would query specific functions in your addon, but that should be pretty easy.

In fact, you may not even need to put the UIWebView in a view anywhere - you could simply instantiate a UIWebView*, load the javascript, and make the calls.

Comment: Awesome! It will take some clever engineering, but at least it's possible. Thanks!

Comment: The impressive part will be when you find out how to make it run *fast* with a game sitting on top of it.

Comment: Yeah man. I guess it's the holy grail of game developers. If I get something working, I'll be sure to open source an example of how to do it efficiently (maybe a framework?).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that downloading and interpreting Javascript is acceptable.

The Facebook and Gmail apps, as well as countless others, do this.